# Comp wont recognize windows 7 install disc after setting up RAID 0 in bios

Tags: windows-7, raid-0

I have a shuttle SN68S with 2 seagate barracuda 7200.11 160GB HD's and a windows 7 disc.  I was running windows fine on one drive, added the other drive, got windows to recognize it in the virtual disk manager.  THen i went into the bios and set up the RAID 0, got it to recognize one 320GB drive in striped 64 bit mode.  exited the raid setup program and put in my windows disc to install windows 7 and it hangs a few lines later at DHCP untill i press escape whitch leaves the nvidia boot agent and then it says DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER.  obivouly i have tried this a 100 times and no matter what OS discs i put in and hit enter or restart same result. I also cannot enter my bios or my boot order screen because by the time my USB wireless keyboard loads up it is a microsecond past the screen where u can press delete to enter the bios or f2 for boot order, so i cant even put it back to regular sata if i wanted to. (comp does not have a socket for the old school keyboard connector, only usb ports and esata cables on the outside) not sure what to do? any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"set up the RAID 0, got it to recognize **one** 320GB drive in striped 64 bit mode."

Raid 0 requires 2 hard drives

Use a regular USB keyboard, not a wireless one.